# Does insert_or_update on a parent table delete child rows in GCP Spanner?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, transactions, google-cloud-spanner

I can't seem to find a definitive answer to this in the documentation for Spanner, but if I `insert_or_update` a row in a `PARENT` table that already exists (so `update`) are existing child rows of an interleaved table deleted or preserved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `insert_or_update` mutation will:

1. Insert a new row in the table that you are operating on if the row does not yet exist.
2. Update the existing row if the row does exist.
3. Keep all child rows untouched in both the above scenarios. It basically behaves the same as how `insert` and `update` would behave.

You can use the `replace` mutation type if you want to delete any child rows and replace the parent row with a new value.

See https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/reference/rpc/google.spanner.v1#google.spanner.v1.Mutation for more details.